# Sending slash and backslash with Java

Tags: java, awtrobot

When using a Java robot, when sending a slash or backslash throws an exception.

For example:

```
public void slash() throws AWTException {
    Robot rob = new Robot();
    rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH);
    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH);
}

public void backSlash() throws AWTException {
    Robot rob = new Robot();
    rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH);
    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH);
}
```

Then, when I want to type those, I use:

```
public void type() {

    try {
        slash();
    } catch (AWTException e) { System.out.println("Exception when typing slash."); }

    try {
        backSlash();
    } catch (AWTException e) { System.out.println("Exception when typing back slash."); }


}
```

I get two error messages in my console. By the way, all other keystrokes I tried to send worked fine.

I get the follwowing stacktrace for slash:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key code
    at sun.awt.windows.WRobotPeer.keyPress(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Robot.keyPress(Unknown Source)
    at com.paschoalinoto.bruno.pastescript.Paste.slash(Paste.java:23)
    at com.paschoalinoto.bruno.pastescript.Paste.type(Paste.java:36)
    at com.paschoalinoto.bruno.pastescript.MainGUI$4.actionPerformed(MainGUI.java:113)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Backslashes work, but also throw an IllegalArgumentException:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key code
at sun.awt.windows.WRobotPeer.keyPress(Native Method)
at java.awt.Robot.keyPress(Unknown Source)
at com.paschoalinoto.bruno.pastescript.Paste.press(Paste.java:198)
at com.paschoalinoto.bruno.pastescript.Paste.paste(Paste.java:173)
at com.paschoalinoto.bruno.pastescript.Paste.finalPaste(Paste.java:227)
at com.paschoalinoto.bruno.pastescript.MainGUI$4.actionPerformed(MainGUI.java:113)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Is there any way I can send slash and backslash keystrokes?

Comment: Please *always* include the result of `e.printStackTrace()` when applicable.

Comment: Well instead of just printing out that there *was* an exception, why don't you print out the exception details?

Comment: For future reference, [here is a great checklist](http://tinyurl.com/so-list) on how to ask a good question on SO.

Comment: Okay.
I added the stack trace. It says invalid key code. But docs say KeyEvent.VK_SLASH is the key code for '/'.

Comment: Do other keystrokes work, or is it just slash and backslash that are breaking?

Comment: All others work. Slash throws that exception. And I have just noticed backslash works, but still throws an exception too. I'll add it.

Comment: What locale do you have on a computer?

Comment: Have you tried a simple program that is just a main with the robot keystrokes? That works fine for me. What is the version and OS of the JVM/JRE that you use?

Comment: @maverik What is locale?

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals I tried it here and it still throws an exception.

Comment: @BrunoPaschoalinoto: In computing, a locale is a set of parameters that defines the user's language, country and any special variant preferences that the user wants to see in their user interface. Usually a locale identifier consists of at least a language identifier and a region identifier (from wikipedia)

Comment: @maverik my locale is PT-BR

Comment: Does `rob.keyPress(47);` works?

Comment: If you could add your OS/JVM build and version details to the question, that would be great as well, since those likely are related to the issue.  (Both methods execute without exceptions for me on 64-bit Windows 7, Java 7u7).

Comment: If you are using a GUI to edit and run this code, be sure you aren't holding any meta-keys when it starts to execute.  Perhaps it doesn't like alt+/ or ctrl+/ or something?  A Thread.sleep(500) at the beginning gave me enough time to get my fingers out of the way.

Comment: @Vulcan OS: Windows 7 Ultimate (64-bit)
        JVM: Java 7u9

Comment: @BillK I'm not, I tested it with 3 secs delay and I still have the exception.

Comment: I think it's because of the keyboard layout. Mine is ABNT2.

Comment: Maybe I could create a method that, based on keyboard layout, sent the correct key...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I have found a solution that may be handy for users working with different keyboard layouts. It uses Alt codes.

```
public static void alt(int event1, int event2, int event3, int event4) throws Exception {

    Robot bot = new Robot();
    bot.delay(50); //Optional
        bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);

            bot.keyPress(event1);
            bot.keyRelease(event1);

            bot.keyPress(event2);
            bot.keyRelease(event2);

            bot.keyPress(event3);
            bot.keyRelease(event3);

            bot.keyPress(event4);
            bot.keyRelease(event4);

        bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);

}
```

Then you call it like this:

For back slashes:
`alt(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0, KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0, KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD9, KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD2);`

For normal ones:
`alt(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0, KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0, KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD4, KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD7);`

No exceptions.
 Also works for all other characters. But make sure you have Num Lock on when using this.

Comment: +1, creative thinking.  Mark this as accepted if it is your final solution.

Comment: For improvement though, don't use a new `Robot` for every call to the method.

Comment: And it is my final solution, but the site won't let me choose it, it says I have to wait 2 days; I'll wait then choose.

Answer (score 2):

(Sorry I should mention this isn't quite an answer, just saying that it does work for me so I'm guessing it's a configuration issue or something--but I thought that it was something others might find handy.  It should be a comment but for technical reasons I have to make it an answer)

I hadn't messed with the Robot class and just spent a FUN half hour messing around and bulding some stuff on top of this cool java class.

For me sending slash and backslash work fine.  Since the VK_??? stuff maps pretty well to the ASCII characters, you can send '\' or '/' and it should work too.

I used Groovy because that's what I play in these days, but here's a nice example and a bunch of reusable code I just came up with.  It's written as a script but could easily be converted to a class in either Groovy or Java (and I will do so soon).

This must be run from a "Priviliged" shell (for instance right-click on the command prompt and select "Run as administrator").

also it MUST have time for you to let go of the keyboard! (Learned that the hard way), so if you use groovyShell and use alt-r to run it, be sure to put a 1 second delay before sending the first keys or your ALT will become part of the keys pressed.

```
import java.awt.*
import java.awt.event.*
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.*

r=new Robot()
r.autoWaitForIdle = true
r.autoDelay=200 // Usually works with 0 but sometimes that's too fast.

// This will alt-tab you to your "Previous" app.  While testing I edited this in notepad++
// then tabbed out to a shell to execute it, this tabbed back into my editor and typed
// the "test" text.
alt VK_TAB

send "backslash=\\ \nforward slash =/"

// This will send any string
def send(String s)
{
    def difference = ("a" as Character) - ("A" as Character)
    s.each {
        Character c=it as Character
        if(c.isUpperCase()) {
            shift c
        } else if(c.isLowerCase()) {
            send(c - difference)
        } 
        else send(c)
    }
}

// These will work for integers and chars, NOT strings
def send(key)
{
    press(key as Integer)
    release(key as Integer)
}
def alt(key)
{
    press VK_ALT
    send key
    release VK_ALT
}
def shift(key)
{
    press VK_SHIFT
    send key
    release VK_SHIFT
}

def press(key)
{
    r.keyPress(key as Integer)
}
def release(int key)
{
    r.keyRelease(key as Integer)
}
```